# Twitch New API : URL (Helix)

Tags: api, oauth, twitch, quartz-composer

Recently, Twitch bring a new API version using new endpoints etc..

I was working on the V5, but I didn't use Curl command line, I work with URL.

So I decide to look at the references of the new version, trying for example to getting the followers and found this :

```
https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows?to_id='user ID'
```

So I replace the `user_ID` by an id (mine and/or another) and get :

```
{
    "error":"Unauthorized",
    "status":401,"message":"Must provide a valid Client-ID or OAuth token"
}
```

When I was working on the V5, I was putting the `client_id` and the `oauth` at the end of the URL like this :

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/CHANNELNAME?client_id=xXxXxXxXxX&oauth_token=aaaabbbbccc111
```

And it was working, but in the new API, I already have a parameter so I added the `client_id` and token after with a `&` connector... But still have the same error.

I also try to put them before the `to_id` parameter, but same...

So my question is really stupid but anyone know the URL format on the new API?

Answer (score 1):

You should send your Client-ID in request's header now, not as a param in URL. But there's other problem with SSL/HTTPS in this case if you use curl.
Here is a solution to your problem

```
DEFINE (TWITCH_API_KEY,'YOUR_KEY_HERE');
$url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams/metadata';
$ch = curl_init();
$headers=['Client-ID: '.TWITCH_API_KEY];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's an obligation to use header now ? Because officially in the V5 it was, but the URL was working :/

Anyway thank you for your response, I have to use url, I'm so sad if helix version disable it :(